# HTML form not sending POST data (or PHP not receiving it)

Tags: php, forms, post

Yes, forms of this question are asked all the time.  Due to the infinite possible ways that one can construct a form/php pair, my question still is different.  (and much simpler)

I have:

```
<html>
<body>
   <form id="request-inspecton" action="test_form_processor.php" method="POST">
      <label class="text-label" for="FirstName">*first name:</label>
      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" required="required" placeholder="First Name">
      <label class="text-label" for="LastName">*last name:</label>
      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" required="required" placeholder="Last Name">
      <input class="button-input" type="submit" value="send" id="buttonSend" name="submitForm" placeholder="Submit form" value="POST">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and:

```
<?php

  var_dump($_POST);

  print $_POST["FirstName"];

?>
```

But all I get is:

```
array(0) { }
```

Golly, I just can't figure out what is wrong!\

Incidentally, example currently at:

http://checkitouthomeinspection.com/test_form.html

Comment: Can You examine the actual http request in Your browser's console? Is it a correct http post request?

Comment: Result from your page: `array(3) { ["FirstName"]=> string(2) "aa" ["LastName"]=> string(2) "bb" ["submitForm"]=> string(4) "send" } aa`

Comment: it posts to test_form_processor.php is this the page with the php code in ? PS that link does not work for me.

Comment: please post the result of phpinfo()

Comment: @Roman, not sure how to do that.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller  how come I don't see that?  Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @Simon.  Yes, test_form_processor.php is the page with the php code.  http://checkitouthomeinspection.com/test_form_processor.php

Comment: @saadzer, I tried typing that at a bash shell, and all I got was a > prompt.

Comment: thanks for the reply i managed to get post data

Comment: @SimonDavies, how did you do it?  What can I do to make my form and code work?

Comment: Ok, now this is strange.  It works in FF but not chrome.

Comment: `var_dump` shows right results in both Firefox and Chrome

Comment: i used your link in chrome and it submitted ok, your not getting any server cache ?

Comment: This is what I get in FF:  array(3) { ["FirstName"]=> string(1) "a" ["LastName"]=> string(1) "b" ["submitForm"]=> string(4) "send" } a

Comment: Is that what I should get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, it now works in both FF and Chrome.  Beats me what the problem was.  Thanks for the help.  Case closed.